c# Winforms: Control inheritance and usage in designer
I've "created" a RichTextLabel, basically a RichTextBox with some properties for the color table and other rtf stuff. Some properties of the RichTextBox are initialized with non-default values in the constructor so it acts more like a Label than a TextBox (f.e.: BorderStyle is set to none, BackColor is set to control, ReadOnly is set to true and so on). Thats all works.
Now i am using this RichTextLabel in a UserControl. I drop it onto the control, design the control, wire everything up and it looks correct in the designer.
This UserControl has an Title property to directly access the Text of the label and also the label itself as public property so i do not need to create properties for each rtf specific stuff on the label that might not be needed at all. This public property is decorated with DesignerSerializationVisibility attribute set to content.
Problem: When drop that onto a form, it first looks ok. The RichTextLabel's BorderStyle is still None. But when i close the form in the designer and reopen it, the border is set to 3dFixed. BackColor is Window an so on, the default RichTextBox properties and not the ones i've used in the RichTextLabel constructor.
May be the designer is using the DefaultValue attribute from the base class as my class does not override the properties (some are not overridable) and can't declare a new DefaultValue for those properties?
Any ideas how i can solve this?
public sealed class RichTextLabel : RichTextBox
{
    [Editor(typeof(MultilineStringEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    public string RtfText { ... }
    public Color Color1 { ... }
    public Color Color2 { ... }
    public Color Color3 { ... }

    public RichTextLabel()
    {
        ReadOnly = true;
        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
        TabStop = false;
        ScrollBars = RichTextBoxScrollBars.None;
        BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
        
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, false);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserMouse, true);

        NativeMethods.HideCaret(Handle);
    }
}

public class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    [Editor(typeof(MultilineStringEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    public string Title { get => richTextLabel1.RtfText; set => richTextLabel1.RtfText = value; }

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public RichTextLabel TitleLabel
    {
        get => richTextLabel1;
        set => richTextLabel1 = value;
    }
}


you can solve Overriding OnHandleCreated in RichTextLabel and reapply these properties there. This ensures your settings persist even after reopening in the designer.
protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnHandleCreated(e);
    BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
    BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
    ReadOnly = true;
}


That partly works. But it just overwrites the (wrong) designer initialization with those constants. It does not correct what the designer is writing and it overwrites every adjustment that is made to the label from the usercontrol (f.e.: a different backcolor)
